# How to get images in Bootstrap's card to be the same height/width?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

So here is my code, it displays 6 cards, three across and two rows. I would like for the images to all be the same size without having to manually resize the images. The responsiveness does work, I use "img-fluid" as a class and when I go to a mobile or smaller browser, they all have the same width, but the height is still off.

```
<h1 class="display-4 text-xs-center m-y-3 text-muted" id="speakers">Ice Cream</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card"><img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/brownie.jpg" />
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Brownie Delight</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Our customer favorite chocolate ice cream jam packed with pieces of brownies and fudge</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card"><img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/butterPecan.jpg" />
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Butter Pecan</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Roasted pecans, butter and vanilla come together to make this wonderful ice cream</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card"><img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/bCherry.jpg" />
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Black Cherry</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Our classic vanilla loaded with plump black cherries to give flavor and color</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card"><img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/mintChip.jpg" />
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Mint Chip</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Our signiture mint ice cream jam packed with mint chocolate chips</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card"><img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/pistachio.jpg" />
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Pistachio</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Our classic pistachio is loaded with nuts to give it that great flavor, and of course comes in your favorite color</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card"><img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/IceCream.jpg" />
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">More Flavors</h4>

        <p class="card-text">We couldn not fit all of our wonderful flavors on one page, click here to see more!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYZ0G.jpg) of what I am getting and this is what I want to [get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwZyH.jpg) where they are all the same size.

Comment: It is Bootstrap, I don't have a css page that modifys anything with the cards, only seperate things. This is what i use on my index.html.                                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437535/card-image-width-not-equal-when-i-gave-max-height

Answer (score 306):

Try this in your css:

```
.card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vw;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Adjust the height vw as you see fit.
The *object-fit: cover* enables zoom instead of image stretching.

Comment: Not supported in IE

Comment: This is a phenomenal answer. Thanks so much. A lot of people could benefit from this one.

Comment: Great solution. Works for me in FF, Chrome and IE 11.

Comment: This does work for the given question, but it breaks the layout when using .card-columns container, and many .card divs (no columns set). It should fill in with cards to all available width, but not it only fills 3 columns. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: @sepuckett86 This seemed to work for me. But there is a vertical/responsive issue - the image stays at 15vw at all breakpoints; that makes the card image look stupidly short when, eg. the card is "col-12" width at "sm". How can we make this responsive?

Comment: @RobertAndrews You can use these responsive breakpoints to increase the height vw at smaller screen sizes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

Comment: GOLD! But note the need for the `object fit polyfill`

Comment: @AliGajani, it is 2020, maybe stop using and supporting IE ?

Comment: @metabuddy Some clients still use it. Why not support IE.

Comment: The longer you support it, the longer people won't quit using it. If they are adamant on using a default windows browser, there is Edge for that, which is much better than the old IE.

Comment: @metabuddy I agree, not supporting IE helps make the world a better place.

Comment: `object-fit: scale-down;` worked better for me...

Answer (score 69):

I solved this problem using Bootstrap 4 Embeds Utilities

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/embed

In this case you just need to add you image to a `div.embed-responsive` like this:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
     <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item" src="img/butterPecan.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Butter Pecan</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Roasted pecans, butter and vanilla come together to make this wonderful ice cream</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

All images will fit the ratio specified by modifier classes:

- `.embed-responsive-21by9`
- `.embed-responsive-16by9`
- `.embed-responsive-4by3`
- `.embed-responsive-1by1`

Additionally this css enables zoom instead of image stretching

```
.embed-responsive .card-img-top {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: I wonder why Bootstrap didn't include the object-fit:cover in the embed-responsive-item class?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice, this has solved so much headscratching

Comment: If you want to use this in BootStrap 5, refer this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/

Answer (score 29):

```
.card-img-top {
width: 100%;
height: 40vh;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

As shown above but when you add height i suggest using "vh" (Viewport Height units) for a more mobile-friendly experience.

Answer (score 19):

```
.card-img-top {
width: 100%;
height: 30vh;
object-fit: contain;
}
```

Contain will help in getting Complete Image displayed inside Card.

Adjust height "30vh" according to your need!

Answer (score 11):

```
.card-img-top {
    height: 15rem;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I went with "manually" using the same breakpoints in Bootstrap 4 as media queries...

```
/* Equal-height card images, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47698201/1375163*/
.card-img-top {
    /*height: 11vw;*/
    object-fit: cover;
}
  /* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .card-img-top {
        height: 19vw;
    }
  }
  /* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .card-img-top {
        height: 16vw;
    }
  }
  /* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .card-img-top {
        height: 11vw;
    }
  }
  /* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .card-img-top {
        height: 11vw;
    }
  }
```

It works, though I wish there were more native responsiveness of this sort.

Partial suggestion from @sepuckett86 and I.

Answer (score 5):

it is a [known issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/22288)

I think the workaround should be set it as

```
.card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the below works for my setup using cards and grid system. I set the flex-grow property of card-image-top class to 1 and the object fit on the same to contain and the flex-grow property of the body to 0.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-4">
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img src="https://i0.wp.com/www.impact-media.be/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/placeholder-1-e1533569576673-960x960.png" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img src="http://www.nebero.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img src="http://www.nebero.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder.jpg" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img src="https://i0.wp.com/www.impact-media.be/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/placeholder-1-e1533569576673-960x960.png" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Test</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.card-img-top {
    flex-grow: 1;
    object-fit:contain;
}
.card-body{
    flex-grow:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont believe you can without cropping them, I mean you could make the divs the same height by using jquery however this will not make the images the same size.

You could take a look at using Masonry which will make this look decent.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 2):

you can fix this problem with style like this.

```
<div class="card"><img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="img/butterPecan.jpg" style="width: 18rem; height: 20rem;" />
```

Comment: Worked like a charm: `style="width: 18rem; height: 20rem;"`

Answer (score 2):

I solved with these:

```
.card-img-top {
    max-height: 20vh; /*not want to take all vertical space*/
    object-fit: contain;/*show all image, autosized, no cut, in available space*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use 'mh-100' to set the max height of the image to 100% and nest it in a parent with a fixed height.

```html
<div class="text-center" style="height: 10rem">
  <img src="https://..." class="img-fluid mh-100" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of the images need to be the exact dimensions before you put them up otherwise bootstrap 4 will try to place them in a funky shape. Bootstrap also has something like Masonry on their documents that you can use if need be, you can see that here, http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#columns.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with these:

```
<div class="card **border-0 p-0**">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to override the css you can do this inline with style:

`style="width: 100%; height: 15rem; object-fit:cover"`

Obviously, you can adjust height to whatever.