# How to make Bootstrap's .card-img-top equal height at responsive widths?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, height, responsive

I am presenting a series of Bootstrap 4 cards like this...

```
<div class="row">

  <!-- column -->
  <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 p-2">
      <!-- card -->
      <div class="card rounded-0 w-100 bg-white">
          <a href="http://www.example.com/destination.html">
            <img src="http://www.www.example.com/images/photo.jpg" class="card-img-top img-responsive w-100">
          </a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">Bookish Blaenavon opens new chapter</h6>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end card -->
  </div>
  <!-- end column -->

  <! -- more of the same cards here +++ -->

</div>
```

All the images may be of unequal dimensions, but, through their class `.card-img-top`, should appear at a consistent size.

**Width:**

FYI - To tackle width, I have already added `.w-100` to `.card` and also to `img`, though I think the latter may be superfluous.

Also, my stylesheet applies `object-fit: cover;` to `.card-img-top`.

It seems to work fine, and means I don't have to use a card deck to force consistency. I'm happy, if it's legit.

**Card Height:**

FYI - To force equal-height cards despite the length of their content, you see I am applying `d-flex align-items-stretch` in the column. Again, happy.

**Image Height:**

*My problem lays here, however.*

To tackle this, I have applied a `height` CSS attribute to `.card-img-top`...

```
/* Equal-height card images, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47698201/1375163*/
.card-img-top {
    height: 11vw;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

The problem is, at every browser width, the `img` stays the same height. That makes it look stupidly short at `sm`, for instance. See this animated example...

[image]

How can I ensure that the image height is really responsive, ie. that its height changes at different breakpoints?

Is there a way to do this using Bootstrap 4 stuff, rather than write media-query code to replicate the same widths it uses?

Does anything I'm doing for width mitigate against the outcome for height?

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this :- https://codepen.io/migli/pen/OQVRMw

Comment: @AnjanaSilva That uses a .card-deck and I don't want to. Or maybe you're pointing at something the CSS is doing with breakpoints? Fair bit of complexity in there which I'm not comprehending.

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437535/card-image-width-not-equal-when-i-gave-max-height

Answer (score 8):

You could set an absolute min and max height on the `img` which would establish a range it could grow and shrink to, for your images for example:

```css
.card-img-top {
    max-height: 200px;
    min-height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">

  <!-- column -->
  <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 p-2">
      <!-- card -->
      <div class="card rounded-0 w-100 bg-white">
          <a href="http://www.example.com/destination.html">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="card-img-top img-responsive w-100">
          </a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">Bookish Blaenavon opens new chapter</h6>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end card -->
  </div>
  <!-- end column -->

  <! -- more of the same cards here +++ -->

</div>
```

You also don't need to set the class of `.w-100` on the image as the `.card-img-top` sets the width to 100% of it's containing element.

Comment: Thanks, 1) but there's something weird happening at narrower breakpoints with Superted, whose image is smaller http://g.recordit.co/vLuvczCGct.gif - like maybe the new attributes are overriding the previous ability to expand that image even if it didn't fill the space. 2) Something doesn't feel quite right, in a responsive sense, about using min/max px values... ?

Comment: 1.) You would need to set the height to 100% for the image to scale (I've updated my answer) 2.)When dealing with responsiveness in regards to layouts personally my main concern is the widths, If you wanted to be truly responsive you should then use different image sizes at different screen resolutions instead of having the large images scale.

Comment: FYI, adding `height: 100%` still leaves an issue with a smaller image now not being scaled to take up the space. eg. Superted.

Comment: Is this only happening for the element containing the "Superted" image?

Comment: No. Here are others when `min-height` and `max-height` are applied - https://i.imgur.com/oQ4CINa.png

Comment: This may be a silly question but have they all got the same classes applied to them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182100/discussion-between-danny-and-robert-andrews).

Comment: This solved my problem in smaller viewports. My images where stretched vertically. Thanks.

Comment: @PauloHenrique No worries, glad it helped!