# image magnifier reset jquery bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking to make a image / card bigger while it is hover then reset after hover. My current code is this

```
var img_css = {"width": "100%", "height": "15vw", "object-fit": "cover"};
var prev_css = $("img").css();
$( "img" ).hover(
    function() {
      $( this ).css((img_css));
    }, function() {
      $( this ).css(prev_css);
    });
```

My answer is based on the stackoverflow answer [How to get images in Bootstrap's card to be the same height/width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287153/how-to-get-images-in-bootstraps-card-to-be-the-same-height-width) although this just stays in hovered state. I can provide html if needed but it looks like `<img style=""class="card-img-top"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2033992/pexels-photo-2033992.jpeg">`

Comment: If you need only to change style, why you dont try to make a card-img-top:hover class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.card-img-top{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
}


.card-img-top:hover{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<img style=""class="card-img-top"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2033992/pexels-photo-2033992.jpeg">
<img style=""class="card-img-top"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2033992/pexels-photo-2033992.jpeg">
<img style=""class="card-img-top"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2033992/pexels-photo-2033992.jpeg">
<img style=""class="card-img-top"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2033992/pexels-photo-2033992.jpeg">
<img style=""class="card-img-top"  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2033992/pexels-photo-2033992.jpeg">
```

Comment: I ended up using css but adding a transform function like this article https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp it is much cleaner ty tho. Still will accept!